# scollbar box with ok button htm and javascript for terms and conditions

Tags: javascript, html

I need to put scroll box with a button for Terms and condition. The button will be enabled only after the user scrolls down the scroll box to ensure that the user has completly read the terms and conditions.

With html, javascript, div, may use php

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to think of it as steps.

You probably should try them separately in order to learn the mechanics.

1. div with a fixed height that will have the content (`overflow: auto`)
2. user scrolls down the div
3. javascript detects the user has reached the end of the div and activates button

Start with simple CSS to put the contents in the DIV and use a fixed height + `overflow: auto`.

Then take a look at this [not to complicated solution](http://yelotofu.com/2008/10/jquery-how-to-tell-if-youre-scroll-to-bottom/) to get the *bottom* of the DIV. This assumes you'll be using jQuery and uses this simple line `Math.abs(inner.offset().top) + elem.height() + elem.offset().top >= inner.outerHeight()` to get your relative position on the DIV.

Hope it helps.

You probably should split the question into sub-questions more focalized on the problems you may encounter as you **try** to develop that.

Comment: I am not that much aware of jquery things, i created the div with fixed hight and overflow auto, how to find out we reached the end fo agreement and enable the button, please give with full code. Pelase frankie

Answer (score 0):

Forcing someone to read terms and conditions might be viewed, at best, as a little bit annoying. Most sites simply ask you to check a box which puts the responsibility in the user's hands. 
Why not use a checkbox system? You can have a page with the terms and conditions plus a checkbox. If the user agrees to read the T&C by checking the box, a button1 appears to take them to your page of choice. 
If the user does not check the box, there is a button2 always visible to take them elsewhere (homepage maybe).

see http://www.ozzu.com/website-design-forum/code-help-hide-button-until-checkbox-checked-t34513.html

Code would go something like this:

```
<form action="termsconditions.ext">

<input type="checkbox" onclick="this.form.go.style.visibility=this.checked ?  'visible' : 'hidden';" />

<input type="button" id= "go" value="continue" style="visibility:hidden" onclick="document.location.href='enter site page';">//button appears after box is checked

<input type="button" value="no thanks" onclick="document.location.href='dont agree page';">//button always visible for user who does not check box

</form>
```